# How to turn off caching of fill patterns in TileMill?

Tags: tilemill, cache, cartocss, url

I'm using CartoCSS in TileMill and png files on disk for filling polygon symbols with patterns.

`polygon-pattern-file: url('sprites/yard.png');`

The display is ok the first time, but when I change the file itself in a raster editor, polygon fills don't change. They do change only if I rename my png file to a different name and make a corresponding change in CSS.

So I guess TileMill caches files for given URLs somehow. How to turn that off?

Answer (score 1):

Since also [Kosmtik](https://github.com/kosmtik/kosmtik) exhibits this behaviour when there have been changes to SVG or PNG files this is rather related to Mapnik than to TileMill. I'm not aware of an option to turn this off. The only solution would be to restart TileMill. Additionally, you could also try to clear the cache folder of TileMill as suggested [here](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/pull/1208#issuecomment-70545852).